# Concat Min-Max GROUP BY to between query

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Good evening all, I have a table which contains like below :

> Category  ID
>   Cat1    1
>   Cat2    2
>   Cat1    3
>   Cat1    4
>   Cat1    5
>   Cat2    6
>   Cat2    7

I want to obtain a result like below

> Cat1 1 - 1
>   Cat2 2 
>   Cat1 3 - 5 (and not 3 - 4 - 5 (I need to select the Min & Max of the list)
>  
>   Cat2 6 
>   Cat2 7

I have began with the query

> SELECT Category, LISTAGG(ID, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Category) AS desc
>   FROM   table
>   GROUP BY Category;

As you see, the Cat1 can contains 2 ID (Min & Max) but it is not the case for Cat2.

Have you an idea about this issue?

I hope to be clear.

thanks.

Cyril

Comment: Why would `cat1` have multiple results (1-1 and 3-5)?

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible in a single query. Can you create a table function? That would make it easy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Cat1 can have multiple results. Yes i can create a table function.

Comment: I assume that you overlooked the output for `Cat2 6-7`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes indeed, I forgot.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using `row_numbers()`.  In fact, it is a difference between the id and a row numbers that identifies a group of sequential ids:

```
select category,
       (case when min(id) = max(id) then id
             else min(id) || '-' || max(id)
        end) as id_range
from (select t.*,
             (id - 
              row_number() over (partition by category order by id)
             ) as grp
      from table t
     ) t
group by category, grp;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this ::

```
select category
     ,min(id) || (case when min(id)=max(id) then 
                                ' '
                           else 
                             '-'||max(id) end) as "MIN-MAX-VALUE"
from temp 
group by category;
```